# Mysql query to get rows with 5 minutes difference

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are linked with foreign key relationship. Both tables have Created Date columns. How can I find all matching rows where time difference is 5 minutes plus or minus.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the timestampdiff function and the abs function, something like this:

```
select * from table1 a, table2 b where a.ID=b.FOREIGNID and ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,a.CREATEDDATE,b.CREATEDDATE)) > 5
```

Documentation for both functions:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Or do you need it for both sides?

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA a
  JOIN tableB b
    ON a.keyInfo = b.keyInfo
   AND b.created BETWEEN a.created - 5/(24*60) AND a.created + 5/(24*60)
```

Comment: Then use Jerry´s answer (probably it has to be <= 5 at the end)